# Filter Suggestions from AutoComplete control

Tags: asp.net, string, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
[WebMethod]
        public string[] GetSuggestions(string prefixText, int count)
        {
            List<string> responses = new List<string>();
            //List<string> lst = new List<string>();
            int str=0;
            IngresConnection conn = new IngresConnection(constr);
            conn.Open();
            IngresCommand cmd = new IngresCommand("select name from addresses", conn);
            IngresDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                if (reader.GetValue(0).ToString().Contains(prefixText) && str<count)
                {
                     responses.Add(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                    str++;
                }
            }
```

I'm using above code to pass the filtered text to the AutoComplete Ajax control.what i need is when i type on the textBox it should populate the suggestions which begins with the Prefix.currently the it populates suggestions where the Prefix contains any where with in the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the solution

```
reader.GetValue(0).ToString().StartsWith(prefixText)
```